How do I Access Keyring Managed Credentials in WordPress?
I'm using a project that uses Keyring to manage credentials.  I've been able to use this to successfully authenticate against an the Google Gmail oAuth API.
What's less clear to me is how I, an end programmer user, am meant to fetch the stored tokens to use in my client API calls.
Is this is a matter of manually querying the posts table to pull out the tokens and use them in my client software?  Or is there a specific API/function/method provided to let me fetch those now stored credentials?

I'm still unsure if this is the intended use -- but from what I can tell Keyring is not just for managing your oAuth credentials.  It's designed for you to use as a client as well.
You can fetch individual tokens using the token store, which you can fetch via a static method call, and then use the get_tokens method to fetch a list of tokens for a particular service.
$store = Keyring::get_token_store();
$tokens = $store->get_tokens(['service'=>'google-mail']);
$token = array_pop($tokens);

Then, you can fetch your service object, set this token on it, and start making API requests
$service = Keyring::get_service_by_name('google-mail');
$service->set_token($token);
$result = $service->request('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages');


